# Upgrading to serviceStack 4

Tags: servicestack

Trying to upgrade my project to ServiceStack 4 (Indie License) and now the following is not valid, anyone know what it is meant to be now?

```
 <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to [read the release notes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes#the-big-refactor-of-v4) which details all the refactors, for which there are many.

The error you are having specifically is this:

> The ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory used in Web.config's handler mapping has been renamed to just ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory

try changing it to `ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory`.

Comment: Managed to work through the rest of the refactorings without needing to read the release notes! this was the last glitch - cheers dude

Comment: @iwayneo No problem, glad it's working. I am planning on upgrading my SS3 app too - I hope it's easy :)

Comment: It's not all that bad - mine isn't a huge app but it's also not small. I think if I'd have read the release docs before trying it would have been even easier! Resharper obviously works it's magic here :)